# Exception: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, build.gradle

I am using SpringBoot with Groovy.

- SpringBoot = 2.7.18
- Java version = 1.8
- Gradle = 8.6
- IDE = Intellij Idea

I am getting the below exception while building the application.

> ### Unable to start the daemon process.
> This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
> For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.For more details on the daemon, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html in the Gradle documentation.
> Process command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=384m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\prashant.sahi.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.6-bin\afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w\gradle-8.6\lib\gradle-launcher-8.6.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\prashant.sahi.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.6-bin\afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w\gradle-8.6\lib\agents\gradle-instrumentation-agent-8.6.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 8.6
> Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>
> ---
>
> Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
> gradle.properties in project root directory

I have tried the following:

- Deleting the .gradle folder from C:\Users$username$.
  -Invalidating all caches and restarting the IntelliJ Idea and my machine multiple times.
- Double checking and even Triple checking the paths to the JDK and Android SDK.

Comment: Spring boot, groovy, and Android SDK? Do you have a simple reproducer that shows what you are seeing when we run it?